# Logging in user on a fronted app using Laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-breeze

This may seem a dumb question for many of you.

So this is my situation :

I have a laravel backend which exposes some API endpoint and uses laravel sanctum to authenticate the requests. This application is hosted at admin.domain.com.

Now I need to build a frontend for users. This frontend will be hosted at affiliates.domain.com.

In this frontend project I already installed laravel breeze react but I'm not sure this is the right way to go.

In my backend app I have a api/v1/login endpoint which accepts an email, a password and a source (string).

This endpoint returns an array of 2 elements if the login is successful, token which is the sanctum token and user which is an array of the user data.

My biggest doubts now are, how do I login on the frontend this user? How do I persist the user data on the frontend?

I notice laravel breeze uses the default laravel Auth which expects an eloquent model but in this case I don't have it as the frontend app has no database.

How should I manage the above situation?

Thank you to all

Comment: I don't get how EVERYTHING you made work because I don't have the source code with me, but from what I understand I would simply keep the token into a session_var in your frontend. Everytime you want to check if the user is connected look if session_var is empty, if it's not look if the token exist in the DB. If yes then get the user related to this token.

Comment: What do you mean by laravel breeze react ? Is it using Inertia ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your frontend app doesn't have a database and it's depend on the backend for user data, you should firstly fetch the user data from your backend after successfull login.
You can return user data on login API response or can provide a separate API for get user data after log in.

Then you have to store user data and login access_token on your frontend.

You have few options.

1. You can use some state management solutions like React's 'useState' or state management libraries like Redux, Pinia, Vuex.This allows you to store user data and access_token on front end.
2. You can use browser local storage for storing user data and auth token

```
    const token = 'yourAuthToken';
    
    // Store the token in Local Storage
    localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
```

3. Session storage
   Similar to Local Storage, Session Storage provides a client-side storage mechanism, but the data stored here is cleared when the session ends (e.g., when the user closes the browser). This can be useful for storing tokens and data that should only persist for the duration of a user's session.
   Then when you call the auth-guarded route on the backend, you can pass this stored token with the request header.
4. You can use cookies to store user data and acess_token also

These are the options you have for storing the user's data and access_token when you log in.

(Not neccesery to install laravel breeze. if you want server side rendering options  ( for SEO or other requreiment ) you can use Inertia JS adapter for rendering react pages directly from the backend without using REST APIS.)